# The sequence {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,...} is (C,1) summable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cesaro-summable

To prove that the sequence 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,... is (C,1) summable:

[A sequence $\{s_n \}$ is (C,1) summable to $L$ if the sequence $\{\sigma_n \}$ converges to $L$ where
$$\sigma_n= \frac{s_1+s_2+...s_n}{n}]$$

My attempt:
Now for our sequence the general term is $$s_n = \frac{1+2\cos (\frac{2\pi}{3}(n+2))}{3}$$

Now $$\sigma_n= \frac{s_1+s_2+...s_n}{n}$$

I.e. $$\sigma_n= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_k}{n}$$

Then $$ \sigma_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+2\cos (\frac{2\pi}{3}(k+2))}{3}$$

$$\sigma _n= \frac{1}{n} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3})+ \frac{2}{3n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos (\frac{2\pi}{3}(k+2))$$

For our sequence i split $\sigma _n $ into 3 cases

Case 1:$ n=1,4,7,12,...$

For $ n=1,4,7,12,...$we have
$$ \sigma_n= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} = 1$$

Case 2: $n = 2,5,8,...$

Here  $$ \sigma_n= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{-1}{3} = 0$$

Similarly case 3: $n = 3,6,9,12,...$

$$ \sigma_n= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{-1}{3} = 0$$

But for $\sigma _n $ to converge the limits must be same in all cases but it is not. Is there any mistake in my calculation or any other way to prove the sequence is (C,1) summable?

Comment: $\sigma_{3n}=\dfrac13$, $\sigma_{3n+1}=\dfrac13\dfrac{3n}{3n+1}$, $\sigma_{3n+2}=\dfrac13\dfrac{3n}{3n+2}$. So?

Comment: Your calcuations for $\sigma_n$ are not correct. I think you've probably made the problem more difficult by bringing in trigonometric functions. For example, you can start by doing some simple calculations to observe that $\sigma_{3k}=\frac{1}{3}$ for the first few values $k \ge 1$, and then you can prove that equation for all $k \ge 1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut how do u get those values for $\sigma_n $ ?

Comment: Trivial for $3n$, then you are adding one or two zeros, they don't contribute to the numerator, so you just have to adjust the denominator by 1 or 2.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've tried calculating but i can generalize it to k and the limits are not same even then

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i don't get ur adjustment in the denominator.  Why is there a 3n in the numberator can please explain so that i can understand and can u look at my calculations,  what is wrong with it?

Comment: If you do the first few calculations manually, $(\sigma_n)$ should be $\left(1, \frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 24, \frac 25, \ldots\right)$, right?

Comment: To get from $x=\dfrac{A}{B}$ to $y=\dfrac{A}{B+1}$, you write $y=x\dfrac{B}{B+1}$. You may write $Bx=(B+1)y=A$ for instance if it's not clear enough. Another way in your case: count the ones in the numerator for a given denominator. It's the same value $n$ for $\sigma_{3n},\sigma_{3n+1},\sigma_{3n+2}$. But somehow the other way was more obvious to me.

Comment: @aschepler yes!! Exactly.. how do i say this is a convergent sequence?

Comment: If you really want to do it your way, note $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3} (k+2)\right)\right) = \left(1, \frac 12, 0, 1, \frac 12, 0, \ldots\right)$$